# After long pressing, pass the touch to another view

Tags: android, ontouchlistener

I have created on view and on long press of that I am generating a duplicate view of the same. Now I want to drag that new View without lifting the finger. Similar to iOS calendar view where we can drag the event just after long press, so the duplicate view on top layer gets dragged with finger without lifting.

Scenario>

> 1)ViewA with long press listener.
>
> 2)After Long press I am generating duplicate ViewADup (Finger is not lifted) on same co-ordinates
>
> 3)ViewADup has touch listener which can follow my finger touch and can be moved
>
> 4) The thing is I cannot figure out how to dispatch continuous touch event to the duplicate view (ViewADup) without lifting the finger.

Help out.
Happy Coding.

Comment: @kling-klang (https://stackoverflow.com/users/2649012/kling-klang) Can you suggest me anything on this?

Comment: The only thing I can think of is passing the received parameters (or some values) to the forcefully called listener on ViewADup. But this would only happen **during** or **after** the even in ViewA. Unless you don't want to stress the CPU by using a timer which would continuously call the listener on ViewADup passing the coordinates read from ViewA. My best suggestion would be: rethink your UI to something less fancy.

Comment: Is it acceptable that you duplicate the view on the same spot and move the original view that registered touch event in the first place? That is easier and achieves the same result imo.